# What should I choose in WCF Security - Transport or Message Security

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

If my Wcf Service and Web Application, both are in same server and if i want to access my web app over internet means which WCF security i have to use and why ?

Please advise me :)

Thanks
Kishore

Comment: That is not enough information. What do you mean by security? Will your server side consume services or client side? Do you have control over your infrastructure? What type of services are you going to build?

Comment: I will have one web app which is hosted in a server. For the data management i am planning to use WCF so that i can handle seurity part using  WCF. So these web application is accessible in internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on binding and the context usage and not on transactions which is a different topic.

The intranet bindings (NetTcpBinding, NetNamedPipeBinding, and NetMsmqBinding) all
default to Transport security. Thus, no special programming is required on behalf of
the service or client developer. The reason is that on the intranet calls are typically
point-to-point, and Transport security yields the best performance. However, the intranet
bindings can also be configured for the None transfer mode; that is, they can be
used on the same transport protocol, only without security. The NetNamedPipeBinding
supports only None and Transport security—there is no sense in using Message security
over IPC, since with IPC there is always exactly one hop from the client to the
service. Also note that only the NetMsmqBinding supports the Both mode.

The Internet bindings all default to Message security, to enable them to be used over
nonsecure transports (that is, HTTP) and to accommodate multiple hops and
intermediaries.

Comment: Hey thomas, thanks for your reply :) Transactions in the sense not the actual in WCF. I meant the data flow between service and the application UI.

Comment: Thomas, can you tell me what is the architecture i have to use. For Example: DataBase -> Data Access Layer -> Buisness Layer -> WCF Service Layer -> Web Application. Is this correct approach or any other ?

Comment: It depends on many things on what you would do and on business requirements also but I would advice you to respect KISS (keep it stupid and simple). Tiers you're talking about make sense to me.